# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'X' referenced before assignment Python for simbols fixer

Tags: python

I have to do a simbols fixer in python for LateX
So I made this code and I dont know why it shows

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Stark's ProBook\Desktop\prueba.py", line 92, in <module>
>     BracketFind()
>   File "C:\Users\Stark's ProBook\Desktop\prueba.py", line 30, in BracketFind
>     for h in archivo:
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'archivo' referenced before assignment
> ```

this is my code is for Python 2.7

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

archivo = open("test.txt", "r")
texto = archivo.readlines()
archivo = "".join(texto)
Opening = 0
Closes = 0
print archivo      

def Count():
    return contador('{')-contador('}')

def contador(simbolo):
    conta = 0
    for h in archivo:
        if simbolo == h:
            conta= conta+1
    return conta

def Insert(string, index):
    return string[:index] + '.' + string[index:]

def Remove(string, index):
    return string[:index-1] + '.' + string[index+1:]

def BracketFind():

    Opening = 0
    Closes = 0
    for h in archivo:
        if '{' == h:
            Opening = Opening+1
        elif '}' ==h:
            Closes = Closes+1

    print "Abiertas ({) "+ str(Opening) + " Cerradas (}) "+str(Closes)
    Position = -1
    StartReplacing = False
    OpenPosition = -1
    while True:
        Position = -1
        StartReplacing = False
        OpenPosition = -1
        if Count() == 0:
            print "Revision exitosa!!, No existe ninguna { sin cerrar " +"Si tienes problemas de compilacion no es por esta razón. " + "Revisa tu codigo en busca de otro error"
            return True
        if contador('{') == 0 and contador('}')>0:
            break
        if contador('{') > 0 and contador('}') == 0:
            break
        for Character in archivo:
            Position = Position+1
            if Character == '{':
                OpenPosition = Position
                StartReplacing = True
            if StartReplacing:
                if Character == '}':
                    try:
                        archivo = Remove(archivo,OpenPosition)
                        archivo = Insert(archivo,OpenPosition)
                        archivo = Remove(archivo,Position)
                        archivo = Insert(archivo,Position)
                    except:
                        break
    iPos = -1
    iCount = -1
    iTarget = 0
    iType = 0

    if '{' in archivo:
        iTarget = archivo.rfind('{')
        print iTarget
        iType = 1
    elif '}' in archivo:
            iTarget = archivo.rfind('}')
            iType = 2
    if iTarget == -1:
        return True
    if iType == 1:
        print "La llave que abre (" , iTarget , ") quizas es inecesaria o parece no estar cerrada"
    elif iType == 2:
            print "La llave que cierra (" , iTarget , ") quizas es inecesaria o parece no estar cerrada"
    for Character in archivo:
        iPos = iPos+1
        if Character == '{' or Character == '}':
            iCount = iCount+1
            if(iCount == iTarget):
               print "La llave ",iCount , "Parece tener error"
    return True

print Count()
BracketFind()
```

Do You have an idea about what is causing this?
I dont understand why is showing this if at the begin of the execution it prints 'archivo'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how python handles scopes. Initially, archivo is a global variable, defined outside any function or class; it can be accessed from any scope. BracketFind() includes several definitions for archivo, ie 'archivo = Remove(archivo,OpenPosition)'. This causes archivo to revert to a local scope for that function; the global variable you are trying to refer to is no longer accessible.

The easiest way to fix this is to add the line 'global archivo' near the beginning of BracketFind(), but a more robust solution will be to rework your code so archivo is no longer a global variable.

Comment: thanks
i made a fix but now it shows me 

"There's an error in your program" and then shows the = simbol with a red on background 


-----------
            if StartReplacing:
                if Character == '}':
                    try:
                        global texto2 = Remove(texto2,OpenPosition)
                        global texto2 = Insert(texto2,OpenPosition)
                        global texto2 = Remove(texto2,Position)
                        global texto2 = Insert(texto2,Position)
                    except:
                        break
                        
        break